# Como corrigir problemas de acentuação em Strings no JTextPane?

Tags: java, swing, codificação-de-caracteres

Tenho uma aplicação em Java, fiz ela no NetBeans. O problema é quando há strings com acentos. Quando executo pelo NetBeans, mostra tudo perfeito (a string com acentos corretamente), mas quando eu crio o JAR e executo-o, as strings são mostradas distorcidas (quando tem acento), por exemplo:

Em vez de:

```
pode atribuir expressão
```

Aparece:

```
pode atribuir expressÃ£o
```

OBS.: As strings são mostradas no `JTextPane`, tenho que usar ele devido a coloração das strings. No Netbeans está configurado para ser UTF-8, mesmo que eu coloque Windows 1252 ou 1256 ainda acontece esse erro no JAR.

Tem alguma forma de ajeitar isso?

Comment: Adicione  o código na pergunta para que seja possivel reproduzir o problema.

Comment: *Quando executo pelo NetBeans, mostra tudo perfeito(a string com acentos corretamente), mas quando eu crio o jar e executo-o, as strings são mostradas distorcidas(quando tem acento), por exemplo :* - Como é que você está criando esse JAR? Qual é o problema em usar o JAR criado pelo NetBeans?

Comment: Crio o JAR quando coloco para compilar( criação padrão do NetBeans). O problema é que quando eu executo pelo NetBeans as palavras são acentuadas normalmente mas quando eu faço a mesma coisa pelo JAR as palavras acentuadas não saem como desejado. É isso que não entendo.

Comment: @Beto Ou seja, trata-se do mesmo JAR? Se sim, isso é estranho. Supostamente o que o NetBeans faz por debaixo dos panos (usando o ant) é apenas um `java -jar SeuJar.jar`.

Comment: Sim, é o mesmo JAR. A GUI foi feita em swing ( não sei se isso ajuda).

Comment: Seria interessante adicionar um [mcve] de código na pergunta, para que possamos simular o problema.